# Can the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1/k)^{3/2}\sin(kx)$ be evaluated using Fourier series or otherwise?

Tags: summation, fourier-series

I have to compute this sum, and I was wondering if it can be evaluated using Fourier series. It seems familiar to me but have forgotten the Fourier tricks I used in the past, so time for revision.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1/k)^{3/2}\sin(kx)$$

Comment: Do you recommend one? (I removed the analysis tag)

Comment: The tags are okay now. I think you meant Fourier series, not Fourier transform.

Comment: Yes, my bad.Thank you.

Comment: The [WolframAlpha output](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sin%28nx%29%2Fn%5E%283%2F2%29+from+1+to+infinity) suggests this doesn't have  a nicer form than the series itself. (Li is just a notation for this sort of sums)

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. So this solves my question and can't be representer nicer as you said. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you both. So in order to ask if this series has weak derivative should I edit the answer or create a new one? I thought a nicer representation could help me find its weak derivative but I suppose I have to ask anyway.

Comment: Ask a separate question. (And try to be clear on the concept of weak derivative you employ.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series, as it stands, is already a Fourier series.

One may express it in terms of the [polylogarithm function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#ii) $\text{Li}_s(\cdot)$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, one has

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^{3/2}}\sin(kx)=\Im\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{k^{3/2}}=\Im\: \text{Li}_{3/2}(e^{ix}).
> $$

You will get different representations of $\text{Li}_s(\cdot)$ [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#ii).